# MySQL OR statement:The same column or multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

Sometimes MySQL doesn't want to use indexes in queries with "or" statements. I wonder what's better - to use "or" statement on the same column or it's better to create multiple columns.
I hope you can understand what I mean. Below are examples.

```
select from table where column1='1' or column1='2' or column1='3';

select from table where column1='1' or column2='1' ir column3='1';
```

Thanks

Comment: Question is : why doesn't it use the index? "Sometimes", they are very good reasons for the optimizer to perform a full table scan instead of  using index. So, have you got a real case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IN` clause like `select from table where column1 in ('1','2','3')`